# How to select multiple child elements of an element

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to get elements using querySelector, id etc . But how to traverse through multiple elements and then chose an elements. Following snippet would illustrate what I am willing to achieve.

Here I wish to traverse to `p` via class `example` and apply some css

```js
function myFunction() {
    //document.querySelector(".example").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.querySelector(".example p").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <div class="example">

    <p>Hello lovely people</p>
    <p>Hello lovely people</p>
    <p>Hello lovely people</p>
  </div>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are lots of properties in the DOM API to navigate from one element to related elements: you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: May be `Element.nextElementSibling`

Comment: @shubhamagrawal my bad Though I get the answer but I am editting my post to avoid any problem in future reference

Comment: @Albzi Sorry but I tried your answer and its working when `p` not wrapped inside `div`

Comment: Well when it is inside the div you just want `.example p` then?

Comment: @Albzi That works.. great !!!

Comment: @Albzi querySelectorAll does not work when multiple `p` tags are there?

Comment: try `.example p:first-of-type`

Comment: @Albzi Only first `p` is affected

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want now. The first p IN .example or after it?

Comment: there are 3 more `p` tags inside .example . I wish to affect them all onclick

Comment: Here is the plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/U1y8U5WKTDLv8OYkSY39?p=preview

Comment: So what was wrong with using `.example p`?

Comment: only first p tag's background color is changing , I wish to change all of p bg inside .example

Comment: You want this then: `function myFunction() {
  var element = document.querySelectorAll('.example p');
  for(i = 0; i <= element.length; i++) {
    element[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}`

Comment: I figured that out :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your question in the comments:

If you have `p`'s inside a `.example` and you want all of them to be changed on button click, you can change your function to this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.querySelectorAll('.example p');
  for(i = 0; i <= element.length; i++) {
    element[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}
```

---

### 'old' question

You can use the `+` CSS selector in your `querySelector`.

Making it

```
document.querySelector(".example + p").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.querySelector(".example + p").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2 class="example">Dont be a racist hate everyone.</h2> 

<p>Hello lovely people</p> <!-- This element I wish to make red -->

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use '[TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker)'. It traverse all the nodes based on the filter provided.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.body, window.NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, false
    ),currentNode;

    currentNode = walker.nextNode();
    while (currentNode !== null) {
        currentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        currentNode = walker.nextNode();
    }
</script>
```

Above example just traverse all ode in `document.body` and apply background color red. 
But make sure traverse from a parent node. In your case, you can put '.example' and 'p' inside a 'div' and traverse

```
<div class="container>
   <h2 class="example">Dont be a racist hate everyone.</h2> 
   <p>Hello lovely people</p> 
</div>
```

and set walker to this container node

```
 var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.querySelector('.container'), window.NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, false
    )
```

Comment: This is interesting code but it is not the easiest way. Thanks though. I will upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the p after the element with the "example" class, use "+" between the class and p.

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.querySelector(".example+p").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2 class="example">Dont be a racist hate everyone.</h2> 

<p>Hello lovely people</p> <!-- This element I wish to make red -->

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works too, using the . (dot) before the class name.

```
document.querySelector("p.example").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

A list of selectors @ [List of CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)